# Insert Item button from within a Radgrid row

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I want to take an already existing row in a RadGrid and instead of open an edit template I want to open the Insert template with that data.

I have a requirement to allow the user to make edits to the rows on their "key" values, the result being a new row that they didnt have to type everything over again.

My guess is to put an insert button on the row, but I'm not sure how to open the insert template and still have it bind that rows data to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put a button inside the grid row (in a template column for instance) and set its CommandName to InitInsert, this should automatically trigger insert when pressed and open the insert form. AFAIK the Telerik ajax grid puts into practice the same event bubbling from commands as the standard MS GridView.